# Django REST Framework serialize hierarchy of two models with FK on each other

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, hierarchy

I have two models, that represent geo information. Layer is the collection of polygons, and Polygon in Layer could reference to another lower Layer

```
class Layer(models.Model):
  ORGANIZATIONS = 0
  DISTRICTS = 1
  REGIONS = 2
  LAYER_TYPES = (
    (ORGANIZATIONS, _("Organizations")),
    (DISTRICTS, _("Districts")),
    (REGIONS, _("Regions")),
  )
  name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
  higher = models.OneToOneField('Polygon', null=True, blank=True,
                              related_name='upper_level')


class Polygon(models.Model):
  polygon_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)   
  layer = models.ForeignKey(Layer)
```

How can I build api, that will work such way:

`/regions_name/` returns:

```
{'region1': 
    {'district1': 
        {'org1': id1, 'org2': id2 },
     'district2': 
        {'org1':  id1}},
 'region2':
    {'district1': 
        {'org1':  id1}},
}
```

`/regions_name/districts_name/` returns:

```
{'district1': 
    {'org1': id1, 'org2': id2 },
 'district2': 
     {'org1':  id1}},
}
```

`/regions_name/districts_name/organizations_name/` returns:

```
{'org1': id1, 'org2': id2 }
```

The whole case [on github](https://github.com/autogestion/corruption_tracker/blob/master/geoinfo/models.py)